# Why was my following edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I suggested the following [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11809827). As far as I can tell I removed all the noise from the question and removed the answer, that was added into the question body and later added into the answers by the OP.

As far as I can tell I also provided a clear edit summary of:

> removed noise, removed answer from question: this has been added into the answers now

Yet this got rejected straight out. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

For reference the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925183/method-to-find-gridview-column-index-by-name).

Comment: not a bad edit. I've gone and edited the post somewhat to this effect.

Comment: Don't let this detract you from editing properly like you did in this case. Sad that you ran across some robo reviewers.

Comment: @Magisch I won't do. Quick question, is there anyway, should there be, a way to post-reject change the status of the review i.e. like mine change it to accepted. Not so much that I get a few points but so the reviewers can see that they did wrong. Maybe like when a editor gets one rejected we get a message saying review recent edits. Something similar as your review was overruled, please review this?

Comment: There are many faults in the review system, I would say generally speaking further fixing it would be better served by reducing robo reviewing, but that suggesiton doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: Reviewers see a big wall of red or green in the edit diff and they instinctively reject. Including a link to the OP's answer in the edit summary might have helped, but maybe not.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Good to know, if I need to do this again in the future I will look into doing that. One more thing to add to try and make the reviewers be more careful I suppose.

Comment: Please keep editing. We need good edits like this.  Meta posts are just fine for when these types of edits get robo-rejected. You're 100% in the 'right' here.

Comment: The edit reviewers each have *just* enough rep to start doing reviews. I'd chalk this up to lack of experience on the part of the reviewers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Answers should be posted as an answer, not in the question. So I don't see anything wrong with your edit.

My guess is that reviewers didn't notice the post is a *question* and not an *answer*, which makes the difference in this case. Please, let's take more time when reviewing posts.

Comment: For future reference, is there anything I could have done better? I thought the line in the summary: removed answer from question was enough

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Your edit and your summary note were very clear. IMO, you did a good job, keep it up.

Comment: Okay thanks, I shall do